# PHP: <div> linebreak with modulo operator

Tags: php, line-breaks, modulo

My PHP code looks like this and produces this line breaking (Bootstrap) [output](http://dev.wohntraeume-soltau.de/category.php).

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($p as $product) {
    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
        echo '<div class="row">';
    }
    echo 'something';
    if ($i % 3 == 2) {
        echo '</div>';
    }
    $i++;
}
```

How to catch up the last missing HTML-`div` to fix the footer?

Comment: What is your **desired** output? You want one `<div class="row">` that contains three `<div class="col-md-4">` or similar products?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48274292/mysqli-how-to-get-and-fill-data-with-3-columns/48274348#48274348

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should close the `div` also when the `$i`-th product is the last one:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($p as $product) {
    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
        echo '<div class="row">';
    }
    echo 'something';
    if ($i % 3 == 2 || $i == sizeof($p) - 1) {
        echo '</div>';
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: @Sirmyself no, because if the last product is a multiple of 3, you would close the `div` twice.