# Dynamically building bootstrap row, 3 per row

Tags: php

I am not sure the best way to go about this, on a site i'm building (using bootstrap) i want to have 3 cards per row using the grid system like:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which is no problem normally, but i'm building it (or trying to) dynamically:

**PHP:**

```
  <main>
    
    <br /><br /><br />
    
    <?php
    
        $pages = array_slice(scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']), 2);    
        $mixed = shuffle($pages);
        $count = 0;

        echo '<div class="container"><div class="row">';    
    
        foreach($pages as $page) 
        {
            $count++;
            if (strpos($page, '.php') !== false && $page != 'index.php') {
                
                $html = file_get_contents($page);
                $code = explode("|", extractXvideos($html));
                
            ?>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                      <img src="<?= $code[3]; ?>" class="card-img-top" alt="<?= $code[0]; ?>">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text"><a href="<?= $page; ?>"><?= substr($code[0], 0, 25); ?> ...</a></p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <?php
            
            if ($count == 18) {
                // The reason only 15 is showing is because we ignore ".", ".." & "index.php".
                break;
            }
            
            }           
        }
        
        echo '</div></div>';        
    
    ?>
    
  </main>
```

For this project i'm scanning .php pages on the server, then trying to lay them out 3 per row, so after every row of 3 i need to start a new row `echo '<div class="container"><div class="row">';` from what i can see, i do not know the best way to go about this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: normalise and filter your data before output, then use modulo on the iteration index https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48274292/mysqli-how-to-get-and-fill-data-with-3-columns/48274348#48274348

Comment: though its bootstrap, just use `class="col-4"`

Answer (score 0):

```
main

<?php
    $pages = array_slice(scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']), 2);    
    $mixed = shuffle($pages);
    $count = 0;
    $output = '';

    foreach($pages as $page) {
        $count++;
        if (strpos($page, '.php') !== false && $page != 'index.php') {
            
            $html = file_get_contents($page);
            $code = explode("|", extractXvideos($html));
            
            $output .= '<div class="container">';
                $output .= '<div class="row">';
                    $output .= '<div class="col">Column</div>';
                    $output .= '<div class="col">Column</div>';
                    $output .= '<div class="col">Column</div>';
                $output .= '</div>
            $output .= '</div>';
        
        }            
    } 
    echo $output;   
?>

main
```

try this template and apply your conditions.